# Generate report for Account User access?

Tags: apex, reporting, sharing, user

How to generate a report for all User having what access to all account records. For this we tried of using UserRecordAccess. But for UserRecordAccess UserId is must and  SQOL limit is 200.  How we can get all user having what access to all Account from the org.

Answer (score 1):

According to [spec](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm) that says

> Up to 200 record IDs can be queried.

reporting won't be easy. The quickest solution that comes to my mind is to get all objects via REST API, i.e. implement the following scenario:

1. Get the list of users you'd like to report.
2. Get the list of records (IDs) you'd like to report and split the list into chunks containing max 200 items.
3. For every user/every chunk of record ids execute via REST API the query:

SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel
         FROM UserRecordAccess
          WHERE UserId = :userId
          AND RecordId in :recordsIds

I think there is no way to dump the whole content of this table.