# Report user access level to accounts

Tags: soql, userrecordaccess

I need to create a report showing all the accounts that a concrete user has access to (it's a similar issue like the reported on [Generate report for Account User access?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53173/generate-report-for-account-user-access))

I've tried to use the UserRecordAccess object (here is the [spec](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm)) to query this information, but I've faced 2 important limitations for this object:

- RecordId MUST be on where clause
- just 200 records can be queried

Getting the list of all users and accounts and query them in chunks is not a viable solution (we are managing about 250.000 accounts, the governor limits for querying objects are a serius issue here)

Does anybody know other way of getting this information?

Thanks in advance